# Sorting output from collections.Counter().most_common() in alphabetical order

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections

`collections.Counter().most_common()` will return entries and their count values from most to least.

I assume for these entries with the same count values, these entries are returned in alphabetical order. However, I found that this is not the case. For example:

```
a =  ["i","i","love","love","leetcode","coding"]

b = Counter(a)

print(b.most_common())
```

This is what I got:

```
[('i', 2), ('love', 2), ('leetcode', 1), ('coding', 1)]
```

`"leetcode"` and `"coding"` are not returned in alphabetical order.

How can I sort from most common to least common, ordering by alphabetical order if two words' counts are the same?

Comment: There is no reason for them to be in alphabetic order, and they aren't.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The answer below gives great explaination that the order is based on which term came first in the original list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.most_common()` will order the elements in decreasing order of frequency, with tiebreaks based on when an element first appears in the list.

The documentation for [`.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) states (emphasis mine):

> Return a list of the `n` most common elements and their counts from the most common to the least. If `n` is omitted or None, `most_common()` returns *all* elements in the counter. **Elements with equal counts are ordered in the order first encountered.**

So, you should use:

```py
sorted(b.most_common(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
```

to resort the elements within each count alphabetically, explicitly encoding the lexicographical order of the element as a tiebreaker.

Comment: another ez way is to sort the original list before using Counter(), thank you for the explaination!